# What are all the ways a monk can benefit from Ki-Fueled Attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, action-economy

The Ki-Fueled Attack optional class feature for monks states (TCoE, p. 48):

> If you spend 1 ki point or more as part of your action on your turn, you can make one attack with an unarmed strike or a monk weapon as a bonus action before the end of the turn.

But looking over the monk abilities that cost ki points, it isn't clear to me exactly which ones count.

Clearly even though bonus actions count as actions, those won't work because you're limited to one a round. Reactions are rarely on your, and some abilities that cost ki points are spells (e.g. the Four elements monk) so you would need to check each one (having looked they all seem to be actions).

This does leave some strange situations where more offensive abilities (like Aspect of the Wyrm) are not compensated whereas, say, casting Pass Without Trace as a Shadow Monk does let you make a bonus action attack.

> As an action, you can spend 2 ki points to cast darkness, darkvision, pass without trace, or silence

Further complications are where you can take a regular actions, and either spend ki point on the condition of causing damage or otherwise, e.g. Deft Strike:

> **Deft Strike**. When you hit a target with a kensei weapon, you can spend 1 ki point to cause the weapon to deal extra damage to the target equal to your Martial Arts die.

Because I'm almost certain there will be monk abilities that I think count that don't and vice versa, as well as the fact I'm trying to pick a subclass for a character I was hoping to find out which of the many monk abilities count for this optional rule?

Comment: Related: "[How do the Ki-Fueled Attack Optional Feature and the Martial Arts Feature differ?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177895)"

Answer (score 6):

The benefits of Ki-Fueled Attack are [twofold](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177895/how-do-the-ki-fueled-attack-optional-feature-and-the-martial-arts-feature-differ): allowing you to make a bonus action attack when not using the Attack action and allowing that bonus action attack to be made with a monk weapon instead of only the unarmed strike allowed by Martial Arts.

Here's a list of monk class and subclass features which qualify for Ki-Fueled Attack while still leaving your bonus action free, broken up according to which of the two benefits they qualify for. Subclass features are followed by the relevant subclass, and those with none listed are standard class features.

Features that don't use the Attack action:

- Empty Body (18th level)
- Quickened Healing (Optional class feature from TCoE) (4th level)
- Hand of Healing (Way of Mercy) (3rd level)
- Hand of Ultimate Mercy (Way of Mercy) (17th level)
- Shadow Arts (Way of Shadow) (3rd level)
- Drunkard's Luck* (Way of the Drunken Master) (11th level)
- Breath of Winter (Way of the Four Elements) (17th level)
- Clench of the North Wind (Way of the Four Elements) (6th level)
- Eternal Mountain Defense (Way of the Four Elements) (17th level)
- Fist of Four Thunders (Way of the Four Elements) (3rd level)
- Fist of Unbroken Air (Way of the Four Elements) (3rd level)
- Flames of the Phoenix (Way of the Four Elements) (11th level)
- Gong of the Summit (Way of the Four Elements) (6th level)
- Mist Stance (Way of the Four Elements) (11th level)
- Ride the Wind (Way of the Four Elements) (11th level)
- River of Hungry Flame (Way of the Four Elements) (17th level)
- Rush of the Gale Spirits (Way of the Four Elements) (3rd level)
- Shape the Flowing River (Way of the Four Elements) (3rd level)
- Sweeping Cinder Strike (Way of the Four Elements) (3rd level)
- Water Whip (Way of the Four Elements) (3rd level)
- Wave of Rolling Earth (Way of the Four Elements) (17th level)
- Touch of the Long Death (Way of the Long Death) (17th level)
- Searing Sunburst** (Way of the Sun Soul) (11th level)

*When used on an ability check made as part of your Action on your turn.
**When spending ki points to increase the sphere's damage.

Features that do use the Attack action:

- Stunning Strike* (5th level)
- Focused Aim* (Optional class feature from TCoE) (5th level)
- Hand of Harm* (Way of Mercy) (3rd level)
- Breath of the Dragon** (Way of the Ascendant Dragon) (3rd level)
- Ascendant Aspect - Augment Breath*** (Way of the Ascendant Dragon) (17th level)
- Drunkard's Luck* (Way of the Drunken Master) (11th level)
- Fangs of the Fire Snake (Way of the Four Elements) (3rd level)
- One With the Blade - Deft Strike* (Way of the Kensei) (6th level)
- Quivering Palm* (Way of the Open Hand) (17th level)

*Provided that the triggering attack was made as part of your Action during your turn, which isn't necessarily always the case for these features.
**Only when used after all uses granted by proficiency bonus have been used, making the feature cost 2 ki, which qualifies it for Ki-Fueled Attack.
***Bypasses the need to expend all free uses of Breath of the Dragon.

Comment: Otherwise noted as 'sneak fix for 4 elements'